# Wordpress deregister jquery - then reregistering with different name causing issues

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I dont like to use plugins but when i do I heavily integrate them. i want to use 1 concatenated JS file for the entire site so I am including any js called by plugins too.

I have deregistered wordpress jquery and I am concatenating my own in with all the plugin js - however, nothing works when this new script with everything is registered like this:

```
wp_register_script( 'production', '/url/production.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

but everything works when I use:

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/url/production.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

Does anyone know any tricks to make this file work and make the plugins recognize it as the official jquery/everything file. Before anyone says just keep it with the name jquery, i cant - for some reason my custom ajax stuff doesnt work when its called jquery.. wierd one.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't other scripts in page that are dependent on jquery? Is the proper file being loaded in page? What errors are thrown?

Comment: It's highly likely that other plugins /themes are checking for the existence of jquery registered and enqueued, and when they aren't finding it are simply failing to load. I believe there are better ways to accomplish what you want to do.  There's plenty of plugins (I know, I know) that allow you to concatenate all scripts / css to save loading time. However, one thing you lose by this method is the advantage of a user already having jQuery cached in browser from a CDN (they probably do). Nothing would be faster than no download at all!

Comment: Funnily enough the plugins to specify jquery as a dependancy, so when you remove/deregister jquery they cannot find it... I solved the issue by creating the script localization strings manually and loading the plugin js into my main file. i dont want to use a plugin for this because speed is the name of the game and I dont want unnecessary php executions especially when I can just concat and minify during build